# Number of Motzkin trees with n nodes

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

I want to calculate $m_n$ - the **number of different Motzkin trees** (Trees where every node has zero, one or two nodes as children) **that contain exactly $n$ nodes**. The position of the children should matter, so e.g. a single node with a single right child should not be considered the same Motzkin tree as a single node with a single left child.

Denote the **family of all Motzkin trees** by $\mathcal{M}$. This structure can be defined by
$$\mathcal{M} := \{O\} \cup \{O\} \times \mathcal{M} \cup \{O\} \times \mathcal{M} \times \mathcal{M}.$$ 
By considering every node should have weight 1, this yields the **generating function** ($M(z) := \sum_{i = 0}^{\infty} m_n \cdot z^n$)
$$ M(z) = \frac{1 - z - \sqrt{1 - 2z - 3z^3}}{2z}.$$
In similar problems I've solved before there was always a rather obvious way to write the function (here $\frac{1 - z - \sqrt{1 - 2z - 3z^3}}{2z}$) as a series and I was able to come to the solution by "reading off" the coefficient $m_n$.

I'm pretty confident my generating function is correct, but can somebody please help me out with the step from $M(z)$ to $m_n$? $m_n$ doesn't have to be in a closed form it could be a sum (or a series?) aswell.

Thank you in advance for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We start with the functional equation

$$M(z) = z + z M(z) + z M(z)^2$$

so that

$$z = \frac{M(z)}{1+M(z)+M(z)^2}$$

We then have

$$n \times m_n = [z^{n-1}] M'(z)$$

and from the Cauchy Coefficient Formula

$$[z^{n-1}] M'(z) =
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^n} M'(z) \; dz.$$

Now put $M(z) = w$ so that $M'(z) \; dz = dw$

and we obtain

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\gamma}
\frac{(1+w+w^2)^n}{w^n} \; dw.$$

This is

$$m_n = \frac{1}{n}
[w^{n-1}] (1+w+w^2)^n
= \frac{1}{n}
[w^{n-1}] \sum_{q=0}^n {n\choose q} w^q (1+w)^q
\\ = \frac{1}{n}
\sum_{q=0}^{n-1} {n\choose q} [w^{n-1-q}] (1+w)^q.$$

We thus have for the desired answer

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
\frac{1}{n}
\sum_{q=0}^{n-1} {n\choose q} {q\choose n-1-q}.}$$

This will produce the sequence

$$1, 1, 2, 4, 9, 21, 51, 127, 323, 835,
\\ 2188, 5798, 15511, 41835, \ldots$$

which points us to [OEIS A001006](http://oeis.org/A001006),
Motzkin numbers, where we have $A001006(n-1)$.

Comment: Thank you very much. This answer really helped me out. Two things aren't 100% clear for me yet. 1) Does $M'(z) dz = dw$ follow from defining $w = M(z)$? 2) Do I get $[z^{n-1}] M'(z) = [w^{n-1}](1+w+w^2)^n$ from $[z^{n-1}] M'(z) = \frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_{|z| = \epsilon} \frac{1}{z^n} M'(z) dz = \frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_{|w| = \gamma} \frac{(1+w+w^2)^n}{w^n} = [w^{n-1}](1+w+w^2)^n$?

Comment: Numbers one and two look correct.

Comment: Hello, good answer, I have a question, why $n\times m_n =[z^{n-1}] M'(z)$ ?

Comment: Because it disappeares when we introduce $dw$, thus avoiding an unwieldy derivative from the functional equation for $w.$